# iOS - Is there a way to toggle accessibility on and off for entire View Controller

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers created with one hidden from the user. Everything works except when accessibility is turned on. Once Siri finishes speaking the elements on the top view, it jumps to the 2nd view controller when I just want it to stop. Is there a way to do this without manually setting each accessibility element On and Off when the other view is off the screen?

Comment: You can turn off accessibility of the root view of the view controller.

Comment: @j.wang using what property?